# How to show Bootstrap Modal after fire jQuery function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, reload

How to show `Bootstrap Modal` after fire `jQuery` `function` ?

This is my function

```
$(".add-to-fav").click(function () {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var is_favorite;

                if ($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-star-empty')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star');
                    is_favorite = 1;
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star').addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
                    is_favorite = 0;
                }

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "files" + "/" + "add_favorite",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {selected_id: id, is_favorite: is_favorite},
                    success: function (res) {
                        if (res)
                        {
                            $("div#result").show();
                            $("div#value").html(res.id);
                            $("div#value").html(res.is_favorite);
                        }
                    }
                });

                location.reload(true);

            });
```

Function is working properly.
I want to show modal with reloading `gif` before fire `location.reload(true);`

Thank you.

Comment: don't do ajax and reload

Comment: why? but I want to send ajax request.function is working properly.

Comment: why was ajax created for?

Comment: If I clicked favorite button in my view, send clicked table row id to controller with ajax

Comment: why don't you do a simple get/post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a bootstrap modal do the following

```
$('#loading-modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: did you change the id of the modal to the id of your modal?

Comment: I throw it before `location.reload(true);`

Comment: add it after event.preventDefault();

Comment: I tried it.But after did it my function isn't working.Thanks to your support.

Comment: yes there is error in console.It says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: are you sure you have bootstrap added to your page?

Comment: yes.Now I did this `$(document).ajaxStart(function () {

                    $('#loading-modal').modal('show');
                });` its working..Thanks a lot  `madalin ivascu`.

Comment: note: ajaxStart is a global function, if you have multiple ajax request it will trigger the modal, you can use the beforeSend property of ajax to tigger the modal, or as i told you you can put the modal show before the ajax call